# ¿Como obtener el código ASCII de la teclas presionada en minúsculas o mayúsculas?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Cuando tecleo siempre sale código `ASCII` en mayúsculas

```js
var texto       = document.getElementById('capture');
texto.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyboardEvent) {
     let code   = keyboardEvent.keyCode;//.key
console.log(code)            
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="capture">
```

¿Como puedo obtener el código `ASCII` respectivo a la tecla presionada minúscula/mayúscula?

Comment: Supongamos que ingresan "a". ¿Necesitas obtener el código ASCII de "a" y  "A"? o solo el código de la letra ingresada ya sea mayúscula o minúscula?

Answer (score 4):

Debes utilizar el evento **keypress** para poder lograr obtener el código de las letras en minúsculas.

```js
var texto       = document.getElementById('capture');
texto.addEventListener('keypress', function(keyboardEvent) {
     let code   = keyboardEvent.keyCode;//.key
console.log(code)            
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="capture">
```

Comment: funciona solo con keypress? o lo sumo 32?

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿por qué usas var para el elemento `#capture` y let para el código de la tecla pulsada?

Comment: hubman: lo que pasa es que keydown y keyup devuelven el código de la tecla presionada en el teclado, y keypress devuelve la letra que estas escribiendo.

Comment: Guz: puedes utilizar var igualmente, pero utilizas let, para definir que el alcance de la variable solo será dentro del bloque de la función, es decir, que cuando finalicen las lineas dentro de la función del listener, la variable code, ya no estará disponible. Para mayor referencia, puedes visitar este enlace. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría así:

```js
var texto = document.getElementById('capture');
texto.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyboardEvent) {
  let code = String.fromCharCode(keyboardEvent.keyCode).toLowerCase().charCodeAt();
  console.log(code);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="capture">
```

o lo que es lo mismo:

```
var texto document.getElementById('capture');
texto.addEventListener('keydown', (keyboardEvent) => console.log(String.fromCharCode(keyboardEvent.keyCode).toLowerCase().charCodeAt()));
```

Básicamente esto lo que hace es que transformar el `ascii` a `char`, luego lo cambia a minúscula y después de regreso a `ascii`.

Comment: Tu código funciona bien, solo hay un detalle si escribo un numero con el teclado numérico este escribe las letras de `a - i ` siendo los números `1 - 9`

Comment: debes tratar de manejar todos los casos si es caracter, numero o caracter especial. Eso mediante un if o case

Answer (score 1):

Tu código está perfecto. Sólo tienes que transformar de vuelta a character y detectar si el evento tiene el modificador [shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey)

```js
var texto       = document.getElementById('capture');
texto.addEventListener('keypress', function(keyboardEvent) {
     let code   = keyboardEvent.keyCode;//.key
     let character = String.fromCharCode(keyboardEvent.keyCode);
     if(!keyboardEvent.shiftKey) {
         character=character.toLowerCase();
     }
console.log({code:code, character:character})            
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="capture">
```

Comment: Tu código funciona bien, solo hay un detalle si escribo un numero con el teclado numérico este escribe las letras de `a - i` siendo los números `1 - 9`

Comment: efectivamente, usando keydown los códigos están desplazados en 48 lugares. Usando keypress (ve la edición de mi respuesta) funciona acorde a lo esperado

Answer (score 1):

Se explica en [KeyboardEvent (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent):

- [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) ( obsoleto). Representa el código numérico, dependiente del sistema y la implementación,que identifica al valor no modificado de la tecla presionada. Es decir que **es el número de la tecla, y no el del caracter ingresado**.

En cambio, podés obtener el valor con:

- [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). Devuelve el valor de la tecla presionada por el usuario. Y, para caracteres imprimibles, devuelve un string que contiene la representación de la tecla (**el caracter**).

```js
var texto = document.getElementById('capture');

texto.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyboardEvent) {
    let tecla = keyboardEvent.key;
    
    //Validamos que no sea "Dead", "Shift", "Control", etc.
    if (tecla.length == 1) {
        let code = tecla.charCodeAt(0); //Obtenemos el código ASCII
        console.log('Tecla', tecla, 'Código', code);
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="capture">
```

> **Nota:**
>
> No se recomienda más el uso de [onkeydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeydown) para interceptar teclas. Entre los puntos principales a mencionar: **no va
>   a funcionar con muchos de los teclados de dispositivos táctiles**. Y,
>   hoy en día, no creo que quieras dejar afuera a la mayoría de los
>   celulares.
>
> Además, si estabas pensando realizar alguna validación, ¿qué debería
>   ocurrir cuando el usuario pega texto sin presionar ninguna tecla?
>
> En cambio, te recomendaría utilizar exclusivamente los eventos que se
>   disparan al modificar un elemento, como [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput), o a lo sumo
>   [onkeypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress).